# Use variables from V-next build into release management 2015

Tags: tfs-2015, azure-pipelines, release-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, vnext

I have created a V-Next build using TFS 2015 and have defined some variables like IPAddress - 
[Screenshot for variable defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qiTO.png)
Now I have to use this variable in my release management while invoking a powershell script.
[Release management variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQH3o.png)
Any idea how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this article to [Configuration variables and system variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/archive/release/previous-version/config-and-system-variables) for release management.

However Release Management features have been integrated into the **Build & Release** hub in Team Foundation Server (TFS) and VSTS.

The newer web-based version is the recommended alternative to the server and client version. If you do not already have Release Management installed, **we encourage you to use the web-based version in TFS 2015 Update 2 and above or VSTS instead of the server and client version**.

Generally in TFS 2015 the custom variables set in build process can not be used in release management. But you can set the variables in release environment. Thus you can use the variables in release process.

[image]

Comment: @Mukul Kazla Have you resolved the issue by the answer above? any update? If that works for you, you could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.